# Set Expiration of QBOE OAUTH token in IPP app for testing of reconnect implementation

Tags: oauth, integration-testing, intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

I see a couple of questions here on StackOverflow about testing OAUTH token reconnect/refresh in IPP apps that integrate with QBOE.  The solutions seem very unuseful to me though, typically pointing to the following page:

https://appcenter.intuit.com/Playground/OAuth/IA/?ck=consumer_key&cs=consumer_secret

However, this doesn't help if we want to do end-to-end testing in a real, non-playground, non-example app, where the tokens are kept in a database that is itself accessed through web services that need to be manipulated when the tokens are granted (or refreshed) by Intuit in the first place.

I really need to certify that our code works to actually refresh IPP OAUTH tokens used for our customers to access their QBOE realms in the ACTUAL context of our working application.  To do this, I need to be able to either generate tokens inside the app (ie using the SDK) that have earlier expirations, or have some way to reset the expiration of an existing connection.

I can't believe I am the only person who would need to do this?

Does anyone have a good technique or strategy in mind?

Many thanks....

Comment: Unfortunately, Intuit doesn't provide a way to do this.

Comment: @Stephan- Keith is right. The only way of testing reconnect is what I have suggested earlier by creating short lived tokens.

Comment: Wow.... I appreciate the comments..... does this seem like a huge oversight on Intuit's part for anyone other than me?  Seems to me that to do end-to-end integration testing, my only option is to use the interactive tool they have provided and run our code in the debugger, and alter the value of the token fields generated to the interactively generated tokens..... hardly standard black box testing for our QA department....